# Google Maps v3 -> Database/mysql -> AJAX -> LOOP -> AJAX -> Loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery, google-maps-api-3

a) the real joke first:
Finally buying Microsoft stuff over the years paid off..
Trying to debug using Chrome, my map was showing just one marker. It was on the correct latlng for the period of the setTimeout, blinks for a small fraction of second, back to same position. 
At a certain time, shot code to Explorer by mistake....... voila... code iterates through the database, but does not use the setTimeout for each marker. At Explorer, setTime out (Ex, 5 seconds), means all the markers will show up, with the right infowindow, but it's 5 seconds for all markers. The longer the time, the longer it will stay in one of them (alwyas the same one), going really fast on the other markers. At chrome, the iteration was so fast I could not see the iteration thru the other latlng's. It was just a blink.

b) I guess the problem is that the getJson (or Ajax), using either for loop or $.each (I used all sorts of combinations.....) is combined with the other loop inside the function changeMarker. So there are two loops going on at the same time. However, I don't know how to fix it. If I close the Ajax (or getJson) right after the $.each or for loop, the rest of the code doesn't get the values. Nothing happens (just my alert, which is for debugging purposes).

No, I don't fully understand closures. Yes, I read a bunch of stuff, the main one [here](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), but also [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) and [here](http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/) and [there](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure). but still didn't figure it out to :/

c) Not easy being a newbie, trying to solve a problem for days... and not getting it solved.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code - omitted a long section where map gets personal options.

```
var BERLIN = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.517683, -46.394393);
var map = null;
var marker = null;
var index = 0;
var infoWindow = null;
var latlng ;
var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';


function initialize() {

    //personal options not included here. 

    var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);

    $.getJSON('php/locationsJson.php',function(json){
        $.each( json, function(i, item) {
            var lat = this.lat;
            var lng = this.lng;

            var location  = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].lat,json[i].lng);                    

            alert( json[i].lat +','+json[i].lng );

            function dropMarker (map, pos){
                return new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location,
                    draggable: false,
                }); // return
            }

            function changeMarker() {   

                if (marker) {
                    infoWindow.close();
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }

                var pos = location[index];
                marker = dropMarker(map,pos);
                var contentString = ('lat: ' + location.lat() + '<br />' + 'lng: ' + location.lng())

                infoWindow.setContent(contentString);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }, 100);

                index = (index + 1) % json.length;

                setTimeout(function () {
                    changeMarker();
                }, 4000);
            } 

            var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

            changeMarker(); 
        }); //$.each                
    }); //end of getjson   
}  //end of initialized
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/NMPRP/)  (thanks for the help to get to that point) for the code BEFORE the AJAX. I tried to add the json file in the fiddle, but it's too complex to add json inside the fiddle.

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: So you are trying to get the same result as seen in the fiddle with the file requested via $.getJSON ?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Yes, same result, but in the feddle I have a static array. This one here, I have ajax to database, dynamic map. I took me several days to get from the static array of maps to the dynamic one, mas I can't get the iteration right. It loops very fast (slower in explorer/firefox) where you can see moving locations, coming back to  a place staying ther for a few seconds, back to a frantic loop. Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: I tried Ajax, getJson, different loops (each, for loop), none delivered the desired result: one marker at a time, a few seconds with the respective infowindow, then goes to next latlng. Something similar to this (http://www.lkozma.net/wpv/). His is way more complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your approach in the fiddle works fine, you don't need much modifications to
achieve it via ajax.

Instead of starting the timeouts inside the loop use the loop only to populate the NEIGBORHOODS-array, and after the loop call `changeMarker()`

The success-callback for $.getJSON:

```
function(json){

  NEIGBORHOODS=[];
  $.each(json,
         function(){
           NEIGBORHOODS.push(new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat,this.lng));
  });
  changeMarker();

}
```

The rest of the code may stay as it is in the fiddle.

Working fiddle with ajax-request:  http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/CVECG/

(Note: In the fiddle I've used `$.post()` because jsfiddle requires post-requests for JSON, you can use `$.getJSON` in your application)

Comment: As beautiful as a poem, as solid as rock. Thank you.